# Listview crashes on scrolling in a fragment under tabhost activity

Tags: android, listview, scroll

My application has two tabhosts and both of them are necessary. I had to use tabhost instead of actionbar as my application need to be supported by the low-end android device.

Now, my `FragmentActivity` has two fragments and one of them has a `ListView`. The `ListView` loads fine but the application crashes with `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when I begin to scroll the list.

My layout for each row is very simple and as i told before it loads first time perfectly and crashes while its scrolled.

I put my logcat here.

```
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971): FATAL EXCEPTION: GUI Thread
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971): java.lang.StackOverflowError
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.graphics.Paint.measureText(Paint.java:1020)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.graphics.Paint.measureText(Paint.java:1057)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.text.Styled.drawDirectionalRun(Styled.java:284)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.text.Styled.measureText(Styled.java:447)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.text.Layout.measureText(Layout.java:1888)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.text.Layout.getLineMax(Layout.java:841)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:386)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:365)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4334)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:6642)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:6428)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1571)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1643)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3207)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3021)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2153)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1964)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1529)
12-02 15:14:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(22971):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTra
```

Comment: `I had to use tabhost instead of actionbar as my application need to be supported by the low-end android device.` You can use `supportActionBar`

Comment: In my case I must use TabHost. And I don't think tabhost is guilty here. There's might be something else.